# Replicate the Excel Chart using Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, data-visualization

I would like to seek help regarding on issue my chart, I would like to replicate this Excel chart into Matplotlib

1. This is the Excel Chart version that i would like replicate
   [image]
2. This is my output in python matplotlib https://pastebin.com/dUr2c7Jq
   [image]

As you can see, the chart displayed was not totally match. So what I'm trying to accomplish is to make the output similar...  Until now I'm bit confused on where the problem really was is in the X-axis or in the Y-axis? And I would like also to have a similar date series X-axis that has some gap but no luck finding the correct settings

I hope anyone can help me to resolve this issue
Though I'm not able to share the Dataset file as its confidential

But I can share my sample code for you to examine

```
import re
import string
import numpy as np
import random
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
import xlrd
import pandas as pd 
from cycler import cycler

def random_color():
    number_of_colors = 1
    color = "#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
    return color

def col2num(col):
    num = 0
    for c in col:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            num = num * 26 + (ord(c.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1
    return num - 1

def cell_number_only(a):
    t = ""
    for ctr in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[ctr].isnumeric():
            t = t + "" + str(a[ctr])
    return int(t) - 1

    
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\LineChart-Dateset-2.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=None)
sheet_Production = df["Production"]

x1 = []
y_wcut = []
y_gor = []
y_qg = []
y_qo = []

# X-axis values (Date)
cell_start = "C6"
cell_end = "C582"
column_index = col2num(cell_start)
row_start_index = cell_number_only(cell_start)
row_end_index = cell_number_only(cell_end)
for ctr in range(row_start_index, row_end_index):
    if not pd.isnull(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]):
        dt = sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]
        x1.append(dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

# Y-axis values (WCut)
cell_start = "N6"
cell_end = "N582"
column_index = col2num(cell_start)
row_start_index = cell_number_only(cell_start)
row_end_index = cell_number_only(cell_end)
for ctr in range(row_start_index, row_end_index):
    if not pd.isnull(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]):
        y_wcut.append(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index])

# Y-axis values (GOR)
cell_start = "P6"
cell_end = "P582"
column_index = col2num(cell_start)
row_start_index = cell_number_only(cell_start)
row_end_index = cell_number_only(cell_end)
for ctr in range(row_start_index, row_end_index):
    if not pd.isnull(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]):
        y_gor.append(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index])

# Y-axis values (Qg)
cell_start = "K6"
cell_end = "K582"
column_index = col2num(cell_start)
row_start_index = cell_number_only(cell_start)
row_end_index = cell_number_only(cell_end)
for ctr in range(row_start_index, row_end_index):
    if not pd.isnull(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]):
        y_qg.append(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index])

# Y-axis values (Qo)
cell_start = "J6"
cell_end = "J582"
column_index = col2num(cell_start)
row_start_index = cell_number_only(cell_start)
row_end_index = cell_number_only(cell_end)
for ctr in range(row_start_index, row_end_index):
    if not pd.isnull(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index]):
        y_qo.append(sheet_Production.loc[ctr, column_index])


s = 20  # size


#print(c)
mpl.rc('lines', linewidth=2, color='g')
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = '#f8ffbd'
mpl.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid.axis'] = 'y'

# host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 10)


plt.xticks(rotation=80)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=11)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelright=True, labelsize=12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.98, bottom=0.2)

# Gridline across y (row)
ax.grid(axis='y', color='gray', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)


# X-axis locator puts ticks at regular intervals
loc_x = plt.MultipleLocator(base=100) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc_x)

# Y-axis base interval for GOR
# loc_y = plt.MultipleLocator(base=10) 
# ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(loc_y)

ax.scatter(x1, y_wcut, s, c="maroon", marker="s", label='Wcut')
ax.scatter(x1, y_gor, s, c="#A933FF", marker="x", label='GOR')
ax.scatter(x1, y_qg, s, c="red", marker="_", label='Qg')
ax.scatter(x1, y_qo, s, c="#099D40", marker="_", label='Qo')


ax.set_ylabel('Oil (STB/D), Gas Rate (Scf/D), GOR (SCF/STB)', color='maroon', fontsize=16);
ax.set_xlabel('Date', color='maroon', fontsize=16)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Watercut', color='maroon', fontsize=16)

# Setting the Y and X axis min-max range (LEFT SIDE)
ymin = 0.1
ymax = 100000
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
# ax.set_xlim([19000.0, 49000.0])
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')

# Setting the Y axis min-max range (RIGHT SIDE)
ymin = 0.0
ymax = 1.2
ax2.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

# Show legend
fig.legend(facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')

# Output
plt.show()
```

I hope anyone can see and help me to resolve my issue.. or redirect me to good reference to solve what I'm trying to accomplish

Thank you in advance

Comment: in Excel, you left y axis is log scaled, try `ax.set_yscale('log')`.

Comment: ok will try that option, but would like have more knowledge in log option? (sorry im still quite new to variables and functions when generating charts)

Comment: similar to Excel, you can change the axis scale from linear (default) to e.g. log scale. See the [docs on set_yscale](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html) for available options and sample programs.